# magento: onepagecheckout, stuck on billing information

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Magento: onepagecheckout, stuck on billing information

This is the response we got:

When I look @ the code in http://baleinen.com/checkout/onepage/ I cannot find an block called shipping-method.

Any ideas howto fix? (and this is the Sentana template, I almost cant imagine that this hasnt worked before)

```
{"goto_section":"shipping_method","update_section":{"name":"shipping-method","html":"    <dl class=\"sp-methods\">
<dt>Betaal en verzendkosten (PostNL)<\/dt>
<dd>
<ul>
<li>
<span class=\"no-display\"><input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flatrate_flatrate\" id=\"s_method_flatrate_flatrate\" checked=\"checked\" \/><\/span>
<label for=\"s_method_flatrate_flatrate\">NL                                                                        <span class=\"price\">\u20ac\u00a01,25<\/span>                                                <\/label>
<\/li>
<\/ul>
<\/dd>
<\/dl>
<script type=\"text\/javascript\">
\/\/<![CDATA[
var shippingCodePrice = {'flatrate_flatrate':1.25};

$$('input[type=\"radio\"][name=\"shipping_method\"]').each(function(el){
Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){
if (el.checked == true) {
var getShippingCode = el.getValue();
var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];
if (!lastPrice) {
lastPrice = newPrice;
quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;
}
if (newPrice != lastPrice) {
quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);
lastPrice = newPrice;
}
checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;
return false;
}
});
});
\/\/]]>
<\/script>
"},"allow_sections":["shipping"],"duplicateBillingInfo":"true"}
```

http://baleinen.com/checkout/onepage/

Comment: review the log files in 'var/log', see if you get any clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that Magento JS was trying to find col-right, when there was none.

This is col-left and reported as a small defect because it i hardcoded in JS

Comment: Great, but you how not answering how to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with OnePage Checkout not completing.

I had to make the following change:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

Find the folowing section:

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and add an id to the fieldset element:

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
   <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now my checkout proceeds OK.